# Are there any advantages to building responsive/mobile websites on a Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

I've been reading that some companies have been moving their mobile platforms to node.js servers. Just wondering what the advantages of building responsive or mobile websites on node.js would be.

Just trying to determine if node.js would be the best choice of server tech in my situation - where i build responsive websites with front end scripting for ui elements, as well as some server/db driven functionality such as blogs.

Comment: For peak performance, you'll want to consider serving your assets (images, stylesheets, ui logic, HTML templates) from a CDN, then have those front-end assets communicate with a fast API.  This is where Node.js excels-- like Erlang, it's asynchronous nature makes it awesome at network io.  Why would you choose Node.js over another option like Erlang?  It's JavaScript, which has that warm fuzzy language familiarity we all know and love!

Answer (score 1):

No, if you are just talking about front end development, it doesn't matter what is actually serving your assets. In fact according to a few stackoverflow posts([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967887/node-js-itself-or-nginx-frontend-for-serving-static-files), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634299/node-js-slower-than-apache))   nginx and apache perform better for serving static assets.

A plus side to node would be to have your stack all use the same language, javascript.  There are all sorts of nifty javascript build tools that are built on and distributed through npm

Comment: agree on the stack part where you just stick on to one language :)